# Bug in HTMLAgilityPack when getting href attribute value. C#

Tags: c#, attributes, html-agility-pack

Found a nasty bug in HTMLAgilityPack whereby some attribute values are NOT returned fully - they are truncated.  Specifically, when attempting to get the href value out of an anchor tag, only the root domain is returned, anything following (the query string) is completely ignored.  Anyone know a good workaround?

Example:

```
node.SelectSingleNode("//link").Attributes["href"].Value
```

returns  **https://www.example.com**
instead of returning **https://www.example.com/mypage.php?_src=ffk_title&ffkid=66534&site=data:http%3A%2F%2Fwww.othersite.com%2Frss%2F**

the link looks like so

```
<a class="tlink" href="https://www.example.com/mypage.php?_src=ffk_title&amp;ffkid=66534&amp;site=data:http%3A%2F%2Fwww.othersite.com%2Frss%2F" target="_blank">Click to get feed</a>
```

Anyway - right now, I'll just get the link tag and parse with old methods - I figure HTMLAgilityPack gets confused if there are atypical characters in the href tag.  I hope it's just something I'm doing wrong, but this kind of quirk is really hurts.

Comment: Can you provide your actual code? `//link` isn't `//a`, and if I change it to `doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a").Attributes["href"].Value` it gives me the full URL as you expect. That's using v1.11.31.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anchor tags, you should use `//a` XPath expression:

```
node.SelectSingleNode("//a").Attributes["href"].Value;
```

Additionally, if you need to reference an anchor with a particular class, you could use:

```
node.SelectSingleNode("//a[@class='tlink']").Attributes["href"].Value;
```

A working example can be seem [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cts7YG).

Comment: I see what I did. I was reusing code for links not anchor tags, and because it partially worked, I figured there was something wrong with the new DotNetCore version of HTMLAgilityWebPath.  I changed it to "//a" and it works fine.  
There is a problem, however. The node was a child of another node - not sure why XPATH parser would look at the parent's parent's node (ie <HTML>) to get the only LINK tags in the document.

Comment: @MC9000 HtmlAgilityPack uses XPath syntax.  In XPath, `//` at the start of a path means "find anywhere in the document".  So `//a` would find all anchors in the document, even if you are starting from a node somewhere in the middle. If you only want to look at descendants from the current node downward, use `.//` as the prefix, e.g., `.//a`.  If you only want to look at direct children of the current node, remove the prefix altogether, e.g., `a`.

Comment: Thanks. Thought it was constrained to the node object no matter the syntax (so // would be "find anywhere", but with respect to the current node object) - to me, that would be the most logical implementation.  I was wrong.